# angularjs nested directive with changing attribute

Tags: angularjs

The directive simply hangs the entire site .. because of the nested directive call .. 
resolve this issue,, i a, abl

Here is my use case ..

Directive definition is given by:

```
app.directive('bluet', function($rootScope,$compile) {
    return {
        scope: {}, 
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $parse, $timeout,$transclude) {
            $scope.val1;
        },      
        templateUrl:"partials/bluetTemplate.html",

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('val1', function(value) { 
                if(value && value != undefined) {
                    scope.val1 =  value;
                }
            });
        }
```

}

and the calling html looks like ...

```
 <bluet val1="{{ val1 +'1' }}"></bluet>
```

the `ng-template` for partials/bluetTemplate.html would look something like :

```
<div>
  <span ng-if="val1=='111'">
    <bluet val1="{{ val1 +'1' }}" ><bluet>           
    <!-- nested call -->
  </span>
  <span>
    {{val1}}
  </span>    
</div>
```

Comment: Since you know the cause of the problem (nested directive), why don't you solve it yourself ? How are e supposed to know in what articular way you want to handle it (and why you created an infinite directive loop in the first place) ?

Comment: Its not a "infinite directive loop" its recursive loop with a end condition. I have custom tree which i want to parse. NOTE that i want to pass params to the tree with 'val1' attribute in the DOM.

Comment: I don't know where you think there is an end condition, but there isn't. The directive will compile forever (as you have already experienced anyway). Maybe stating what you are trying to achieve might help someone propose a better approach (i.e. one that does not cause the browser to crash).

Comment: <span ng-if="val1=='111'"> is the condition when it will call itself ... else it will stop ,, the resursive condition is complex in my case,, but i have simplified here

Comment: This condition will be evaluated during the link-phase. But before that comes the compile-phase that will first try to compile the template and will result in an infinite compiling loop.

Comment: can we skip the initial compilataion.. or should we initialize to something dummy and re-compile with `attrs.$observe('val1', function(value)`

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution, but I would check the value of `val1` during the link-phase and compile and append a nested `bluet` element if necessary. I'll try to put a short demo together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ngIf` directive will check the "end condition" during the post-link phase, while the template will be compiled during the compile phase, ther will be an ininite compile loop.

A possible approach would be to check the "end condition" (i.e. the value of `val1`) in post-link phase and (if necessary) create, compile and insert a new `<bluet>` child element dynamicaly.

E.g.:

```
app.directive('bluet', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><span>{{val1}}</span></div>',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.val1 = attrs.val1;
            if ((scope.val1 !== undefined) && (scope.val1 !== '111')) {
                var bluet = angular.element(
                    '<bluet val1="' + scope.val1 + '1"></bluet>');
                $compile(bluet)(scope);
                elem[0].insertBefore(bluet[0], elem[0].firstChild);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/AUYF9/)**.

Comment: Always glad to help ! Feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked :)

Comment: Don't have enough pts at this moment .. but will definately do that .. once i have it ..

Comment: I believe 15 pts are enough for an upvote (and you seem to have 43) :)

Comment: ah.. didn't knew abt this.. really